# Which version of Stewart for GRE Math?

Tags: gre-exam

I am planning on taking the GRE Math Exam and wanted to know which version of Stewart Calculus is useful for this exam as there are many versions of the book.

Comment: You can use that which has single and multivariable calculus

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Do you have any idea which version has single and multivariable calculus? Coz many people recommend using Stewarts Calculus for GRE prep and I dont know which book to buy.